# On click give variable another value

Tags: php, html, pagination, onclick

I am trying to implement pagination functionality to a page. I have custom post types and I have looped through and gathered all the posts for this page. I display the first post and hide the rest and I have next/previous buttons that will show the next post and hide the current post. It seems to be working, however I am not able to view all the posts - only 2 of them.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
            $currProj = 1;
            $countposts = 3;
            ?>
                <?php if ($countposts>1) { 
                    $prevID = $currProj - 1;

                    if ($prevID <= 0) { 
                        $prevID = $countposts;
                    ?>
                        <a class="btn-previous" href="javascript:showProject('<?php echo $currProj; ?>','<?php echo $prevID; ?>')" onclick="<?php $currProj=$prevID; ?>"> < Previous </a>
                    <?php } else { 
                    ?>
                        <a class="btn-previous" href="javascript:showProject('<?php echo $currProj; ?>','<?php echo $prevID; ?>')" onclick="<?php $currProj=$prevID; ?>"> < Previous </a>
                    <?php 
                    //$currProj = $prevID;  
                    }

                    echo $currProj; //This outputs 3 where it should be 1
                    $nextID = $currProj + 1; 

                    if ($nextID > $countposts) { 
                        $nextID = 1;

                    ?>
                        <a class="btn-next" id="nextlink" href="javascript:showProject('<?php echo $currProj; ?>','<?php echo $nextID; ?>')" onclick="<?php $currProj=$nextID; ?>"> Next > </a>
                    <?php } else { 

                    ?> 
                        <a class="btn-next" id="nextlink" href="javascript:showProject('<?php echo $currProj; ?>','<?php echo $nextID; ?>')" onclick="<?php $currProj=$nextID; ?>"> Next > </a>
                    <?php 
                    //$currProj = $nextID;
                    }

                } ?>
```

The javascript function is working correctly, the issue seems to be the $currProj variable. I think the issue is my onClick attribute in the  tag - is there a better way of having an onClick event that will give my variable a different value? Or a way of checking if this link has been clicked then give the currProj the value of prevID/nextID ?

I have been stuck on this for a while now and I don't seem to be getting anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `onclick="<?php $currProj=$prevID; ?>"` are you trying to compare? Or are you just assigning? In either case, you need to put `echo` : `onclick="<?php echo $currProj=$prevID; ?>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above seems to be conflating what's happening on the server side and what's happening on the client side.  Anything wrapped in `<?php` ... `?>` is going to be executed on the server and then sent to the client as HTML -- for example, this line:

```
<a class="btn-previous" href="javascript:showProject('<?php echo $currProj; ?>','<?php echo $prevID; ?>')" onclick="<?php $currProj=$prevID; ?>"> < Previous </a>
```

will end up being sent to the client with all of the PHP interpreted:

```
<a class="btn-previous" href="javascript:showProject(1,3)" onclick=""> < Previous </a>
```

The key thing here is this you're **not** re-running the PHP when you click -- the client is completely agnostic to the PHP ever having been there.  Every time you click the Previous button, its `href` attribute is still `javascript:showProject(1,3)`.

You have two options; namely, you can go back to the server and have it re-render the page whenever you click the next / previous button by including those variables as parameters to your page, e.g., get the current project from the URL and link like so:

```
$currProj = ( $_REQUEST['currProj'] ? $_REQUEST['currProj'] : 1 );
...
<a class="btn-previous" href="<?php echo '[your_url_here]?currProj=' . $prevID ?>">
```

However, it looks like you're interested in doing this without ever pinging the server again.  In that case, you'll need to store, reference, and update these variables in javascript.  There are probably a thousand ways to do this; the closes to what you seem to want to do would be to have your `showProject` function take no arguments and instead figure out what it needs to do based on the value of the current project, something like

```
var currProj = <?php echo $currProj; ?>; // this initializes the JS variable currProj from whatever it is in PHP when the server sends the page contents
var countposts = <?php echo $countposts; ?>; // initialize this too
var showPrevProject = function showPrevProject() { 
  // hide the current project using jQuery; assumes the DOM element you want to hide is given ID #project-[currProj]
  $('#project-' + currProj).hide();

  // Update the current project variable in JS; scope should update globally
  currProj = currProj - 1;
  if (currProj === 0) { currProj = countposts; } 

  // Now show that element
  $('#project-' + currProj).show();
}
```

Then in your link you can use `showNextProject` or `showPrevProject` as appropriate.

More generally, though, it's probably better to include your javascript as a separate file and register event handlers to deal with this sort of thing.  I would also recommend checking out [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), which is a powerful library that greatly simplifies accessing and manipulating DOM elements.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply - I had to put this project aside for a while but I am back on it now.

Thank you so much for your help! What you said and the logic makes a lot of sense to me, however I seem to be having trouble implementing it. I'm sure I am just overlooking something silly. 

I used the code you gave above, however it gives an error 

"SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'
var currProj = ;"

So it doesn't seem to be passing the $currProj variable.

Secondly I am not sure how to pass those "showPrevProject"/"showNextProject" variables in my link.

Comment: @annie-d To pass the javascript function, try using `onclick="showNextProject()"` in your anchor tag (see https://jsfiddle.net/h19w79zj/ for an example).  For the `currProj` issue, is the variable defined in PHP by the time that you're running the assignment in JS (`var currProj = <?php echo $currProj; ?>;`)?

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a HTML hidden input for storing those values?

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $currProj ?>" id="currProj">
```

So you can access it and modify it in client side with javascript or jQuery. If you want a solution server-side you can do it with ajax and POST or GET requests.

Maybe this isn't what you are looking for (modify the php attributes) and I misunderstood you. Let me know if this is your case.